# Connecting to Aster Teradata Python

Tags: python, database-connection, teradata, teradata-aster, aster

I want to connect to Teradata Aster, I have been searched through multiple sites and read documentation but with not luck. I am able to connect to Teradata just fine, but not to Aster Teradata.

code for teradata that works, but I don't know how to tweak this to work for aster:

```
import teradata
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="TDD...", username="...", password="...", authentication="LDAP");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to Aster use native Teradata Aster ODBC driver. Follow [this link](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/aster) and choose "Aster Client Tools" for your platform to find and download the driver.

Then use a [Python package for ODBC database connectivity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBC) such as `pyodbc`. I used similar method in R but never with Python, one example I found for Python and Teradata is [here](http://downloads.teradata.com/forum/connectivity/getting-both-teradata-odbc-and-aster-odbc-working-together-with-the-pyodbc-python).

Comment: Thank you, I tried your recommendation but it didn't work. Maybe I'll try connecting using R instead.

Comment: I used R RODBC package and had no problems on Windows, but never tried that on Mac. Eventually, it'll be all about ODBC support on a client side. You can related example here: http://rpubs.com/grigory/introtoaster

Comment: Update: thank you again for all your help, because of your advice I was finally able to connect to Python as well. I first connected to R and it took me a few more days to figure out why Aster can connect to R but not Python.

Comment: @MariaNazari how did you end up connecting to python ?

Comment: @toceto download pyodbc and the aster driver like topchef mentioned and use the following syntax to connect: conn = pyodbc.connect(
                        'DRIVER={Aster ODBC Driver};SERVER=xxx.xxx.xx.xx; PORT=xxx;DATABASE=xx;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx)